# What does ^$1$ mean in bash and why doesn't it work in zsh

Tags: bash, grep, zsh

I have recently moved from `bash` to `zsh` and one of the little scripts I found a long time ago stopped working.

The script shows what packages depend on the package specified.

```
comm -12 <(pactree -ru $1 | sort) <(pacman -Qqe | sort) | grep -v ^$1$ | sed 's/^/  /'
```

After some time messing with it around I found out it breaks at `grep -v ^$1$`. Back then, when I found the script I tried googling to learn what does it mean but unsuccessfully. Now that it broke itself I'm even more interested in what it does and how exactly does it work.

So, the question is, what does `^$1$` mean and how to get it to work in `zsh`? Thanks!

Edit:
Okay, `^` and `$` are regular expressions, I see. RE is the topic I always laid aside as it requires a lot of free time and willingness to study. The question is, why doesn't it work in `zsh` as it is a `grep` feature and the shell shouldn't interact with it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `^` is an anchor for start-of-line. `$1` is expanded to the first parameter (the same one used for `pactree`). `$` is an anchor for end-of-line. `grep -v` greps for lines *not* containing the pattern. That means this lists all lines that are *not* "just" whatever is in `$1` (i.e., that and nothing else). No idea why it doesn't work in `zsh` though (never worked with that), hence only a comment.

Comment: Text is usually preferred over screenshots. And no, `^` and `$` are not RE's, the whole thing `^$1$` is an RE, `^` and `$` are just elements of RE syntax. Generic complex expression debugging advice: Check the output of the *first* part of the expression (`pactree -ru gtk3` in your case), look for differences. *Then* add the next part (`| sort` in your case). Repeat until you found the exact point where outputs differ. (Which would allow you to reduce your question to one that doesn't include e.g. `comm`, or `pactree`, if it's really just about the `grep`...)

Comment: (ctd.) I don't even have `pactree` installed, let alone having your file structure, so I can't "trial & error" with your expression. At the moment I'd probably add quotation marks around the `^gtk3$` and see what happens. (I am guessing that zsh expands the `^gtk3$` *before* passing it to `grep`. As I said, I don't have any experience with zsh.)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a pair of double quotes around the `^$1$`. For some reason `bash` worked perfectly without the quotes yet `zsh` didn't like it at all. The fix is actually a lot easier than I expected but that's just because I didn't know that that was a regular expression(thanks, @DevSolar).

If one wants the final script for pacman to check what packages depend on a specific package, here it is

```
comm -12 <(pactree -ru $1 | sort) <(pacman -Qqe | sort) | grep -v "^$1$" | sed 's/^/  /'
```

}

Use it in a function or in a shell script.

Edit: I figured what was the problem by myself before @DevSolar suggested it but I'm still very grateful for the help :)

Comment: My pleasure. ;-) (Bash doesn't support this kind of RE expression, so it just shrugs and passes it to `grep`, with or without quotation marks.)

Comment: `zsh` was probably treating it as a pattern that didn't match any files, which by default is an error.

Comment: Feel free to upvote some of @DevSolar 's other Answers here on S.O. Glad you got a solution. Good luck to all.